# Regular expression to trip beginning and ending from certificate PEM string

Tags: regex, certificate

Certificate PEM files contain the beginning and end like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- [Base64 of certificate] -----END CERTIFICATE
```

I need to extract just the `[Base64 of certificate]` part, i.e., strip off the `"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- "` and `" -----END CERTIFICATE-----"` strings , and was wondering if this could be done with a regex, and if so what would that regex look like?

I've tried:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- (.*) -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

but, rather than giving me the Base64 of the cert, it's returning everything.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: given that - would not appear anywhere inside the main base64 block, my take on this in java would be: str = str.replaceAll("-+.[A-Z ]+-+", "") - this would cover also other things like CSR and keys.

Answer (score 4):

Since i don't know the language you use, I give you a relatively portable pattern (must support lookahead and lookbehind):

```
(?<=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- )(?:\S+|\s(?!-----END CERTIFICATE-----))+(?=\s-----END CERTIFICATE-----)
```

the result is the whole pattern since lookarounds are just checks.

Answer (score 3):

In perl:

```
my base64_cert_data;
if ($certbuf=~/(-+BEGIN CERTIFICATE-+)(.*?)(-+END CERTIFICATE-+)/s) {
    base64_cert_data = $2;
}
```

Regex Explanation :

```
/(-+BEGIN CERTIFICATE-+)(.*?)(-+END CERTIFICATE-+)/s

1st Capturing group (-+BEGIN CERTIFICATE-+)
    -+ matches the character - literally
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    BEGIN CERTIFICATE matches the characters BEGIN CERTIFICATE literally (case sensitive)
    -+ matches the character - literally
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
2nd Capturing group (.*?)
    .*? matches any character
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
3rd Capturing group (-+END CERTIFICATE-+)
    -+ matches the character - literally
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    END CERTIFICATE matches the characters END CERTIFICATE literally (case sensitive)
    -+ matches the character - literally
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi below is a sample perl code to support your requirement.

```
my $Str = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
if($Str =~ /^\W+\w+\s+\w+\W+\s(.*)\s+\W+.*$/s) {
    print "$1" . "\n\n";
} else {
    print "No\n" . "\n\n";
}
```

### Output:

```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```

Answer (score 1):

The base64 character set is:

`[A-Za-z0-9+/\r\n]+={0,2}` - this is an accurate description of what is typically used for PEM files (base64 certificates). `=` is for padding (at the end) and `\r\n` are new line characters.

Putting it all together we get:

```java
"-+BEGIN\\s+.*CERTIFICATE[^-]*-+(?:\\s|\\r|\\n)+" // Header
 + "([A-Za-z0-9+/\r\n]+={0,2})"                   // Base64 text
 + "-+END\\s+.*CERTIFICATE[^-]*-+"                // Footer
```

If you wanted to be language agnostic, you could expect the header/footer to be one or more `-` chars followed by CAPITAL letters only followed by, again, one or more `-` chars.

Comment: In viewing a few questions, this is the only attempt to validate the base64 encoding.  I still had to modify a bit to '-+BEGIN[a-zA-Z ]*-+\\n[A-Za-z0-9\/\\n+]+-+END[a-zA-Z ]*-+\\n'.  Then again I was checking for keys not certificates.

Comment: you can, in some programming languages, ignore case-sensitivity entirely to simplify things a little. Keys typically have CERTIFICATE in the header/footer and keys will have KEY.

Answer (score 0):

Here is regex:

```
(?<=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----)[\s\S]*?(?=-----END CERTIFICATE-----)
```

Java example:

```java
        final String text = Files.readString("file.txt") // file with certs ;
        final List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----)[\\s\\S]*?(?=-----END CERTIFICATE-----)")
                .matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            final String m = matcher.group()
                    .replaceAll("\\n", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\r", "");
            results.add(m);
        }
```